# How to parse RSS feed details view without UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, rss

I'm designing an RSS feeder using `**XCode**` and `**Objective-C**`. However I'm a little confused on how to create the article view page without `UIWebView` in a manner similar to how Apple's News app does it.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually its pretty straight forward. u just need to use textlabels and UIImage / TextViews.

Just parse the feeds and display the appropriate contents in their respective fiels

i.e images in imagview and title in TextLabels.
If u want the UI to look good u can add appropriate graphics.